# Accidently disabled all services via msconfig

Tags: windows-10

I was trying to debug explorer hangs and accidently disabled all services via msconfig. Now the Windows 10 boots up but there is no login screen. Trying to get into safe mode but shift+restart does not work.

How can I restore my system back to working condition?

Comment: If you have the Windows ISO, you can try a repair by keeping your files and settings by booting with the ISO

Comment: @dsstorefile1 that was the solutionm